# Is the South Africa border control able to cross-reference dual citizen passports (USA & Spain)?

Tags: us-citizens, dual-nationality, overstaying, south-africa, spanish-citizens

I would like to travel to South Africa as a tourist 6-months after I overstayed a SA visa due to emergency hospitalization. As a result of the overstay I was classified as undesirable & am restricted from re-entry for 1 year (under the new May 2015 SA Home Affairs policies). The overstay is associated with a US passport but I am also a citizen of Spain with a Spanish passport.

Is the SA border control electronic system at the Johannesburg International airport able to cross reference passports from 2 nations (e.g, by name & birth date)?

Has anyone had experience crossing the SA border with the undesirable status?

Comment: Not the SA border, but my observations are that sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. Sometimes they find out later.  But when it doesn't work, you are tagged as an illegal entrant.  They will also tell the DHS about it.

Answer (score 4):

The overstay is associated with **you**, identified by a US passport. Your Spanish passport also identifies you. Maybe they will be able to cross reference the passports, and if they do, the consequences will be serious since you are seen to be knowingly violating your terms of restriction.

Are you willing to take that chance?